# My a.exe file appears to be corrupted. (C language)

Tags: c, exe, malware, antivirus, mcafee

The a.exe file is quarantined (contained in an isolated folder) by my anti-virus McAfee stating that it protected me from a virus. It didn't happen right after I started coding with C. Infact, I was able to write some 7 or 8 programs using VS Code and they all ran well. Now, out of the blue, the anti-virus quarantines the a.exe file. I can't run any C programs without the a.exe file.

How do I solve this problem? Is there any way of getting the a.exe file back? I am scared to disable my anti-virus and run codes as I don't want malware to infect my computer. Please help me.

---

Comment: Add the folder you're working in to antivirus exceptions. This sometimes happens.

Comment: Just uninstall McAfee. This software is the actual virus in your computer. Let Windows Defender/Windows Security do McAfee's job better, for free, without bloating your computer.

Comment: If McAfee only reports that a file you compiled is infected, but the rest of your computer is not, then it is likely a false positive.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel No, McAfee didn't report any file that I compiled. It only reported the executable a.exe

Comment: @Biskweet Why do you say that?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you, but if my computer does get infected, how will I know about it and what should I do after that?

Comment: `a.exe` *is* the file you compiled. *"if my computer does get infected, how will I know about it"* I suggested to only add one folder to exceptions. As long as you don't use the same folder for e.g. running random executables downloaded from the internet, you should be good.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The a.exe file isn't used outside of C programming in my computer. So, if I put it into antivirus exceptions, I should probably be good is what you say?

Comment: I didn't say to add `a.exe` to exceptions. I said to add the **whole folder** you do programming in to exceptions.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh, sorry. I read your statement wrong. So, if I put the folder I'm using for C coding into antivirus exceptions, I should probably be good?

Comment: Yes, it should work.